# Helm-mode change default keybinding for "helm-find-files-*" * -> "down-one-level" (?)

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, helm, emacs24

I wan't to switch the keybinding in helm-find-files when I go one level up or go in to a folder. Now it looks like:

- ***"C-j"*** -> go in to the folder
- ***"C-l"*** -> go one level up

For me, it's intuitive to switch them, so it will be the following:

- ***"C-j"*** -> go one level up
- ***"C-l"*** -> go in to the folder

I could replace the ***"C-j"*** to the one I wanted with this:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-j") 'helm-find-files-up-one-level)
```

I don't know what's the action's name to "*go in to the folder*". If I find it out, that could be a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running `helm-find-files`, you should be able to use `C-h k C-j` to find out what command will be run by `C-j`, for me, it gives:

> C-j runs the command **helm-execute-persistent-action** (found in
>   **helm-find-files-map**), which is an interactive Lisp closure in
>   ‘helm.el’.
>
> It is bound to , C-j, C-z.
>
> (helm-execute-persistent-action &optional (ATTR 'persistent-action)
>   SPLIT-ONEWINDOW)

and to avoid affecting the key bindings in other helm commands, you should change `helm-find-files-map` instead of `helm-map`, so the following is probably what you want:

```
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-j") 'helm-find-files-up-one-level)
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-l") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```